# Optimal way to add functionality to classes - PySpark

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, oop, pyspark

A while a go I was looking for how to rename several columns at once for a PySpark DF and came across something like the following:

```
import pyspark
def rename_sdf(df, mapper={}, **kwargs_mapper):
    # Do something
    # return something

pyspark.sql.dataframe.DataFrame.rename = rename_sdf
```

I am interested in that last bit where a method is added to the pyspark.DataFrame class through an assignment statement.
The thing is, I am creating a Github repo to store all my functions and ETLs and I thought that if I could apply the logic showed above it would be super easy to just create an **__init__.py** module where I instantiate all my functionalities like:

```
from funcs import *
pyspark.sql.dataframe.DataFrame.func1 = func1
pyspark.sql.dataframe.DataFrame.func2 = func2
.
.
.
pyspark.sql.dataframe.DataFrame.funcN = funcN
```

I guess my question is:

Is this useful? Is it good for performance? Is it wrong? Is it un-Pythonic?

Answer (score 0):

That can definitely have its uses in certain scenarios. I would recommend putting this code into a function so the user must explicitly call it.

```py
import funcs


def wrap_pyspark_dataframe():
    pyspark.sql.dataframe.DataFrame.func1 = funcs.func1
    pyspark.sql.dataframe.DataFrame.func2 = funcs.func2
    ...
```

Comment: Great! Thanks. Do you know if it punishes performance? or is it the same?

Comment: It will depend on what you are replacing. If you are replacing heavily optimized code with slow code, obviously a big difference. The reassigning of the methods themself will be negligible.